# Steepest Descent using Armijo rule

Tags: matlab

I want to determine the Steepest descent of the Rosenbruck function using Armijo steplength where x = [-1.2, 1]' (the initial column vector).

The problem is, that the code has been running for a long time. I think there will be an infinite loop created here. But I could not understand where the problem was.

Could anyone help me?

```
    n=input('enter the number of variables n ');

% Armijo stepsize rule parameters
  x = [-1.2 1]';
  s = 10;
  m = 0;
  sigma = .1;
  beta = .5;
  obj=func(x);
  g=grad(x);
  k_max = 10^5;
  k=0;                 % k = # iterations
  nf=1;               % nf = # function eval.
  x_new = zeros([],1) ;    % empty vector which can be filled if length is not known ;

  [X,Y]=meshgrid(-2:0.5:2);
  fx = 100*(X.^2 - Y).^2 + (X-1).^2;
  contour(X, Y, fx, 20)  


while  (norm(g)>10^(-3)) && (k<k_max)
    d = -g./abs(g);                   % steepest descent direction
    s = 1;
    newobj = func(x + beta.^m*s*d);
    m = m+1;

    if obj > newobj - (sigma*beta.^m*s*g'*d)
        t = beta^m *s;
        x = x + t*d;
        m_new = m;
        newobj = func(x + t*d);
        nf = nf+1;
    else
        m = m+1;
    end
    obj=newobj;
    g=grad(x);
    k = k + 1;
    x_new = [x_new, x];
 end

% Output x and k
  x_new, k, nf
  fprintf('Optimal Solution x = [%f, %f]\n', x(1), x(2))
  plot(x_new) 
  
  function y = func(x)
  y = 100*(x(1)^2 - x(2))^2 + (x(1)-1)^2;
  end

function y = grad(x)
y(1) = 100*(2*(x(1)^2-x(2))*2*x(1)) + 2*(x(1)-1);
end
```

Comment: You should add a maximum iteration to your while loop. Easier to debug too.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thank you. I have done that. I want to visualize the iterations. Could you tell me how can I plot the values?

Comment: just store the value of `x` in an array, then use `plot` when it finishes.

Comment: @AnderBiguri How can I reduce the array size? My program is showing that there is not enough memory.

Comment: I am sure you have a problem with the code, can you update it with the new one? To not have enough memory you must be doing billions of iterations, not possible. Or running on a computer from the 70s

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have edited the code. I know , there is  problem in the code, but could not understand where it is.